# C# How do I get data from Database to textboxes

Tags: c#, database, combobox, oledb

Greetings programmers,

I have a combobox and some textboxes in my windows form connected to a database. My idea is, when the value of the combobox changes the data in the textboxes changes too. Like when I pick a customer ID in the combobox, the textboxes will be loaded with the data of the customer, like the Full name or the address etc. But when I open the Form the combobox disapear's and the textboxes stays empty. I am using Access database and Visual Studio 2012 to code. Here is my code..

**C# code**:

```
private void comboBox1_SelectedValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string pc = Convert.ToString(comboBox1.SelectedValue);
        string sql = "SELECT * FROM Customer WHERE CustomerID="+ pc;
        Data.Customer_Data(sql, pc);

        txtfullname.Text = Data.fullname;
        txtadress.Text = Data.adress;
        txtcity.Text = Data.city;
        txtemail.Text = Data.email;

    }
```

And my class called Data:

```
public static string cs = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + Application.StartupPath + "\\Database1.accdb";
public static string fullname = "";
public static string adress = "";
public static string city = "";
public static string email = "";
public static void Customer_Data(string sql, string pc)
    {
            if (pc == "")
            {
                return;
            }

            else
            {
                OleDbConnection oleDbConnection1 = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection(cs);
                oleDbConnection1.Open();
                OleDbCommand oleDbCommand1 = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand(sql,oleDbConnection1);
                OleDbDataReader reader = oleDbCommand1.ExecuteReader();

                if (!reader.Read())
                    return;

                fullname = reader["fullname"].ToString();
                adress = reader["adress"].ToString();
                city = reader["city"].ToString();
                email = reader["email"].ToString();


                oleDbConnection1.Close();
            }
    }
```

Comment: W00t the comboBox disapears ? have you set the comboBox property visible to false ?

Comment: what code do you have in your form_Load event?

Comment: No, it just disapears

Comment: this.CustomerTableAdapter.Fill(this.database1DataSetUltimate.Customer); Fills the combobox with Items. I think the problem is the reader because when I commend out the parts that needs the reader (and the reader self) the combobox appears and contains items from the database

Comment: if you set a BreakPoint right before comboBox1_SelectedValueChanged exits, what values do you have in string pc?

Answer (score -1):

You can try one of the following debugging techniques and see what is happening .

1. After this line `Data.Customer_Data(sql, pc);` does the data for the properties load properly?
2. Can you also check if there are database values for the corresponding customer id passed ? so that this condition `if (!reader.Read()) return;` is not executed.
3. Check you page load method( i am sure it doesn't play with the visibility of the combo box, but hey there is no harm in trying).

If none of them mentioned here work then may be some more code will help.

Comment: Do try reader[0] instead of reader["fullname"] and reader[1] for reader["adress"] respectively.

Comment: Also check if the static variables of the class are messing up something.

Comment: I have found the problem, its my database, an other table has a space in the name.. Visual Studio doesnt like that.. Thanks for the anwser anyway